# In Snowflake what is difference between SF staged and SF table storage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake what is difference between SF staged and SF table storage.

--Staged storage

put file://C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\JC-202002-citibike-tripdata1.csv @%Trips2;

--Table storage

create table  DEMO_DB.PUBLIC.Trips1
(tripduration integer,
  start_station_id integer,
  start_station_name string,
  start_station_latitude float,
  start_station_longitude float,
  end_station_id integer,
  end_station_name string,
  end_station_latitude float,
  end_station_longitude float,
  bikeid integer,
  usertype string,
  birth_year integer,
  gender integer);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal table storage in Snowflake is structured, uses [columnar storage formats](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-key-concepts.html#database-storage), a form of [partitioned layout](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-micro-partitions.html), and [more](https://www.snowflake.com/resource/sigmod-2016-paper-snowflake-elastic-data-warehouse/). You cannot directly access a table's underlying storage specifics, and the only way to add data into a table is by use of [specific](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide-data-load.html) [statements](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql-dml.html).

A [stage](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system-create-stage.html), including the [table-named internal stage](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system-create-stage.html#table-stages), is roughly equivalent to a cloud storage bucket and path used to keep raw files for the purposes of eventually loading it into a table (or the opposite, to unload a table's rows into raw files for exports).

The `PUT` statement in your description will help encrypt and upload local files into a cloud storage location used by your Snowflake account. You'll have to use the `COPY INTO TABLE` statement to subsequently load it into the table your `CREATE TABLE` statement has created, to query the data efficiently.